# How to show that $\Bbb Q$ is incomplete under this special metric?

Tags: general-topology, complete-spaces

Fix a prime $p$ and a positive rational number $r$ can be written uniquely in a form $r=p^e\frac{b}{c}$, with $e\in \Bbb Z$ and $p,b,c \in \Bbb N$ being pairwise coprime.

Define $|\cdot|_p$ as

- $|r|_p=0$, if $r=0$,
- $|r|_p=|-r|_p$, if $r<0$,
- $|r|=p^{-e}$, if $r=p^eb/c$.

The special metric is defined as $d(r_1,r_2)=|r_1-r_2|_p$.

I meet this problem in exercises, I want to construct a Cauchy sequence such that the difference of two items is of the form $p^e$, and show its limit is irrational. But I am confused with how to show a limit is irrational.

Are my thinkings right? I just want some hints (solution better).

Comment: How do you have $r<0$? You consider $b,c$ to be in naturals?

Comment: So basically the metic is $d(x,y)=-\min \{ \nu_p(x),\nu_p(y) \}$ right?

Comment: Can you find a suitable $p$ and a suitable sequence that "converges" to $\sqrt2$? (Or another favourite irrational).

Comment: @Shamim The form $p^eb/c$ is for positive rational numbers.

Comment: Oh i see. $ $ $ $

Comment: @AnginaSeng I want to do that, but I don't know how to represent those items with an arbitrary prime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the $p$-adic metric on $\Bbb Q$.

Textbooks describe how if $p$ is odd and $a$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$
then $x^2=a$ is soluble in the $p$-adic numbers by using a method called
"Hensel lifting". This involves constructing a sequence of integers converging
to a square root of $a$ modulo $p$, so this sequences of integers is a non-convergent
Cauchy sequence within $\Bbb Q$.

But we can proceed more naively using fixed point iteration. Let $p=7$
and $a=2$. Take $x_0=3$, so that $x_0^2\equiv2\pmod 7$. Define a sequence
$(x_n)$ recursively by
$$x_{n+1}=\frac12\left(x_n+\frac2{x_n}\right).$$
It's easy to show that $x_n\to\sqrt2$ inside $\Bbb R$ but we want this to be
true in our metric, more precisely $|x_n^2-2|_7\to0$.
In fact $|x_n^2-2|_7=7^{-n-1}$ and $|x_{n+1}-x_n|_7=7^{-n}$ (exercises for reader).
From this one deduces that $(x_n)$ is Cauchy, and if $x_n\to a$ then $x_n^2\to a^2$,
but $x_n^2\to2$.